# Laravel registerPolicies always get "This action is unauthorized."

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel 5.5 I create the policy

```php
public function view()
{
    return true;
}
```

and register it in the `AuthServiceProvider`

```php
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

In the controller I use the policy like this:

```php
$this->authorize('view');
```

I get the error `This action is unauthorized` whether the function `view()` returns true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy is registered for the Post model.

I assume your `view()` method is inside the PostPolicy class. It appears as if you'd want to use it without a model instance.

Use `$this->authorize('view', Post:class);` if the policy code does not require a model instance.

Your view method should furthermore receive a user model.

`public function view(User $user) { ... };`

Otherwise, for whom would you want to check permissions.