# Laravel 5.5: Authorization Policy AccessDeniedHttpException This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, policy

I created a policy for authorization, so I faced with this problem.

I have seen these solutions, but my problem didn't solve yet:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906101/laravel-authorization-policy-accessdeniedhttpexception-this-action-is-unauthoriz)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631548/laravel-registerpolicies-always-get-this-action-is-unauthorized)

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126737/policy-returns-this-action-is-unauthorized-no-matter-what)

Here are the Codes:

Function used in ArticalesController Class:

```
public function show(Articale $articale)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $articale);
    return view('articales.show',compact('articale'));
}
```

ArticalePolicy Class:

```
        <?php

        namespace App\Policies;

        use App\User;
        use App\Articale;
        use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

        class ArticalePolicy
        {
            use HandlesAuthorization;

            /**
             * Determine whether the user can view the articale.
             *
             * @param  \App\User  $user
             * @param  \App\Articale  $articale
             * @return mixed
             */
            public function view(User $user, Articale $articale)
            {
                return $user->id == $articale->user_id;
            }
```

AuthServiceProvider Class:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Articale::class => ArticalePolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with your model name as like this replace it with your `AuthServiceProvider`

replace

`Articale::class => ArticalePolicy::class,`

with

`'App\Articale' => 'App\Policies\ArticalePolicy',`